# телевизор не воспроизводит mkv

Tags: видео, ffmpeg

Телевизор не воспроизводит конкретный mkv файл, хотя с другими mkv файлами проблем нет. По видимому это связно с тем, что число референсных кадров в этом файле слишком большое(12).
Можно ли с помощью ffmpeg изменить это число? Если можно, то дайте пример командной строки.
Насколько я понимаю, изменение числа референсных кадров требует перекодировки. Какой формат выбрать для конечного файла, если требуется сохранить исходное качество и получить максимальную скорость перекодировки?